# How can I acess a def outside of a if/elif statment

Tags: python, function

I m trying to make a game where you type in commands and the game responds. There is one section of the game where you have to choose a path and type in 1 or 2 and it brings the user to either the path1() or path2() def but when I get to the part and type one path one does not run it just brings up the >>> asking me for a command you can view the whole project here --> https://github.com/CodeMaster-exe/thepengogame but here is the part I am having trouble on.

```
    elif cmd == "job hut":
        print("Manager: How may I help you?")
        print(f"{user}: Can I get a job?")
        print('''
        Manager: I have 2 jobs to offer: 
        Job 1: A Community manager
        Job 2: A Money manager
        ''')
        sleep(1)
        hmhy1r = int(input("Which would you like? Job (1) or Job (2)?: "))
        if cmd == 1:
            path1()
        elif cmd == 2:
            path2()


    # paths
    def path1():
        print("hi")

    def path2():
        print("Working on path 2 taking you to path 1 in 3 seconds")
        sleep(3)
        path1()
```

I know I start with an elif but there is an if statement above it so do not mind. there is also a while loop running the `cmd = input(">>> ")` but it is all the way at line one. So again you can view my full program at github the link in above.

Comment: Did you mean: `if hmhy1r == 1:`?

Comment: Also, you need to define your functions before you invoke them, often at the top of a script.

Comment: @jjramsey: That's not necessarily the case.

Comment: As far as I know, in Python, if you try to call a function before it's been defined, you'll get a `NameError`. Just try opening a Python prompt and running `foo()`.

Comment: @quamrana Yes I did That was the soulution

Comment: @jjramsey: I take it from the response of the OP that my suggestion fixed their problem and the program can now successfully call `path1()` or `path2()`.

Comment: @quamrana But that's only because *two* `while` loop iterations were run in the sample execution. In the first one, when "c" was used for `cmd`, `path1` and `path2` were defined. In the second iteration, when "job hut" [sic] was used for `cmd`, `path1` and `path2` still retained their definitions from the previous iteration, so they could be invoked.

Comment: @quamrana If the functions had been defined near the bottom of the script but *outside* the `while` loop, the attempt to invoke `path1` or `path2` would have failed.

Comment: @jjramsey: Ok, I looked at the code in the link and you're right. I had assumed that the calling code was itself inside a function which was called at the bottom of the script. That would work. The code in the link won't, just as you say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to compare `cmd` which is not the variable you have stored the use input in.

Since you written

```py
hmhy1r = input("Which would you like? Job (1) or Job (2)?: ")
```

You need to check for `hmhy1r` value

```py
        hmhy1r = int(input("Which would you like? Job (1) or Job (2)?: "))
        if hmhy1r == 1:
            path1()
        elif hmhy1r == 2:
            path2()
```

---

```markdown
PENGUIN ADVENTURE PRESS A TO BEGIN
>>> c
What is your name ?: Sigma
What is your age (please no decimals)?: 20
Now you will be prompted to enter some info
Please enter a user name: Sigma
Now is when the Teaching begins press d to start
>>> job hut
Manager: How may I help you?
Sigma: Can I get a job?

        Manager: I have 2 jobs to offer: 
        Job 1: A Community manager
        Job 2: A Money manager
        
Which would you like? Job (1) or Job (2)?: 1
hi
>>> job hut
Manager: How may I help you?
Sigma: Can I get a job?

        Manager: I have 2 jobs to offer: 
        Job 1: A Community manager
        Job 2: A Money manager
        
Which would you like? Job (1) or Job (2)?: 2
Working on path 2 taking you to path 1 in 3 seconds
```